# Planning tag improvements: radio programming and interfacing

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We got a question about “programming radios” (that is, bulk entering frequency memories and configuration, from a computer or other radio) that was tagged [programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) (which says it is for software development); I believe this has happened before. I noticed that we don't actually have a good tag for that concept, and I used [equipment-operation](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment-operation) as the closest relative, but it's a poor fit because questions on the subject involve things like [making custom cables](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/6732/is-it-possible-to-program-the-vertex-vx-2200-using-the-back-db-15-pin-connector).

I've also noticed that we have no tag that well fits questions about “CAT” (controlling a transceiver in normal operation from a computer), other than [remote-control](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-control) (and many uses of CAT are not remote).

I'm thinking that these are related gaps, but I am uncertain of what to do. Here are some ideas (neither all compatible nor all mutually exclusive). I'd like some input on good naming and whether these tags should exist.

- Create [radio-programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-programming).
- Rename [programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) to [computer-programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-programming) or [software-development](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development) or some such name. (Ideally both this and the radio programming tag would contain the word 'programming' so that people typing into the autocompleting tag box get cued to disambiguate, but it should also not be long/clunky.)
- Create [cat](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cat) or [computer-control](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-control).
- Create something like [equipment-interfacing](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment-interfacing), which covers radio programming, CAT, and even [audio wiring](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1933/using-standard-headphones-with-the-yaesu-ft-60) (but excluding [antenna-system](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antenna-system) and [dc-power](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-power) matters). Either **instead of** or in addition to the above specific ones.

Comment: what is the "consensus" ? -- just curious.

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo Well, as you can see, no one else has spoken up much. My current plan is to make some of these changes gradually (particularly, creating the tags I proposed creating), but not before making a list of questions to which they would apply to see how useful they'd actually be.

Comment: Sure, go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have now actually done, which is not quite the same as the plan I laid out above:

- Created [computer-control](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-control) and made [cat](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cat) a synonym of it.
- Created [radio-programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-programming).
- Created [audio-interface](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio-interface), for headphones/speakers, microphones, sound card interfaces, etc., and eliminated [audio](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) as not having a clearly different use. (Some questions specific to microphones, mostly “is this mic compatible with this rig”, I left as [microphone](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microphone) only.)
- Renamed [programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) to [software-development](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development), and created the synonym [computer-programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-programming) to help autocomplete.

In particular, I did not create the broad tag [equipment-interfacing](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment-interfacing) even though it would suit some questions that almost-fit several of the above tags (e.g. [Looking for a UHF / VHF transceiver for PC.`](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/4996/looking-for-a-uhf-vhf-transceiver-for-pc) and any TNC-related questions) or even ones that don't fit any of them (e.g. [Using a flip-phones GPS NMEA data for the GPS in an APRS station](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/2432/using-a-flip-phones-gps-nmea-data-for-the-gps-in-an-aprs-station)), because I think it's not something that people would *think of using* consistently, whereas the above all have names that are very straightforwardly related to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [equipment-interfacing](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment-interfacing) you should be consistent and use [equipment-programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment-programming) in stead of [radio-programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-programming), so I would suggest the following:

- [radio-programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-programming) --> [equipment-programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment-programming)
- [programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) --> [software-development](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development)
- [cat](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cat) or [computer-control](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-control) --> [computer-control](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-control) as you may have equipment which can be controlled other than CAT interface, example: WiFi, Ethernet.
- [equipment-interfacing](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment-interfacing) --> agree for those instances where you connect two devices together for purpose other than [equipment-programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment-programming) and other than [computer-control](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-control)

[Edit:2016-10-17, based on comments]

I don't believe [equipment-programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment-programming) is "peculiar", hence I cannot answer to why someone would. And I would not change any other [equipment-something](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment-something) for that matter. [radio-programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-programming) is fine if the majority agrees.

in regards to "CAT" interface, the reason that I suggest [computer-control](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-control) is that many people (as I have experienced) identify "CAT" with a physical interface on their equipment, not like Ethernet. Hence [computer-control](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-control) may be more appropriate than [cat](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cat) or [cat-control](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cat-control). However we can leave [cat](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cat) to indicate posts which really have to do with CAT interfaces.

Comment: "equipment-programming" seems to me to be far too peculiar a term to use for the sake of consistency. If we don't use "equipment-programming", what other "equipment-" names would you want to change instead? Also, what does "CAT interface" mean to you that it excludes Ethernet?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the proposed [cat](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cat),I'm under the impression that CAT refers to a specific plug and jack on certain Yaesu, Icom, and Kenwood radios.  I have an Elecraft K2, and Elecraft never refers to its computer control capability as "CAT" in the manuals.  Because CAT seems to be brand-specific, I think [computer-control](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-control) would be better than [cat](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cat).  I'd say that we shouldn't create [cat](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cat) for interfaces actually labeled CAT, because most people would think it's a synonym for [computer-control](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-control).  [equipment-interfacing](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment-interfacing) just sounds too vague to cover the serial interface used to control a radio, in my opinion.

I think there is definitely a need for [radio-programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-programming) or [equipment-programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment-programming).  I think people would be more likely to find [radio-programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-programming), but in my opinion there would be no harm in creating both tags as synonyms.

If [programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) has been misused, then in my opinion it needs to be changed.  Either [computer-programming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-programming), or [software-development](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development), or both as synonyms would be fine by me.